# Confounder real definition

Tags: mathematical-statistics, causality, definition, confounding

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Cn1smM3kbQ), I can see that confounding variable is a variable that is **correlated** with two other variables:

[image]

But this image tells that confounding variables is **causally related** to other two variables:

[image]

So is confounding variable defined as something that is **correlated** or **causally related**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable whose value would be correlated with, but not causing **any** response in a target value is one that is *caused **by** your target*. So, correlation seems like a poor criterion for a confounder.

Every causal confounder will be correlated with the target - more or less by definition - so chances are the video creator either phrased things poorly or didn't think it through.

Comment: Thanks! So the correct definition is the one on the second picture, right?

Comment: I would say so; I don't like the fact the arrows only go *from* the confounder there though. They can go in both directions as well (bidirectional causation), just as long as they don't **only** go from the target to the confounder.